# Recover data from lists in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have two lists in python, say A and B.

**List A** is a list of lists with some integer indexes, for example `[[2,3,1,3,2,3,3], [4,2,1,4],[5,4,3,3,3,4,]...]` and so on.

**List B** has the same structure but instead of integers has numpy arrays. 
`[[array([0, 0]), array([0, 0]), array([0, 1]) ...][[array([0, 0]), array([0, 1])...]...]`

These lists are correlated, so each numpy array corresponds to a integer, in other words, the sublists of A and the sublists of B has the same size. For example

`[[2,3,3,3,2,4]...]`

`[[array([0, 0]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 0]), array([1, 0])]...]`

The first integer in the sublist of A, "2" is linked to the first numpy array in the sublist of B.

As you can see there are repeated integers, and in consequence repeated numpy arrays. I want to recover the unique indexes without repeating, and thus their corresponding arrays.

Taking the example above the return of the procedure should be something like this:

`[[2,3,4]...]`

`[[array([0, 0]), array([0, 1]), array([1, 0])]...]`

**How can I recover the unique elements from list A with their corresponded numpy array in list b?**

My first attempt used the `numpy.unique` function so i can recover list A efficiently, but then I lose the information to recover the information from B. The line was

```
A = np.array([np.unique(a) for a in A])
```

**TO RECAP**
I have the following

```
import numpy as np
A = [] # PUT A REAL (short) LIST HERE 
B = [] # PUT A REAL (short) LIST HERE
uniqueA = np.array([np.unique(a) for a in A])
print uniqueA #prints what I want/dont want
expectA = [1,4] # put what you would expect to get back
#ask additional questions here
```

Comment: I dont understand the question ... and I assume im not alone ... it would help if you included a minimal working example, along with what you expect to get back(the actual list or whatever) as well as what you are currently getting back and whats wrong with what you are currently recovering

Comment: I put a desired output example. I am currently recovering nothing because of my shortminded approach of recovering the unique elements of A but not enough information to recover the np.arrays from B

Comment: Should integers be unique across all sublists or just within a single sublist each?

Comment: The integers are unique within each sublist :)

Comment: a minimal working example please ... that means a block of code I can copy and paste to get the same output `[1,2,3,...]` is a syntax error(as Im sure you are aware). in fact the only valid line of python i see is `A = np.array([np.unique(a) for a in A])` Im making no promises of being able to help but if you want someone to help you will need to provide __one block of python code that someone can simply copy and paste to get your same output__  I have added a skeleton outline to your question, you will need to complete it in order for it to make sense

Comment: I'll be back soon, I have found a problem in my code!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get unique indices of `A`, then take them from `A` and `B`

```
import numpy as np

A = [[2,3,1,3,2,3,3], [4,2,1,4]]
B = [[np.zeros(2)]*len(A[0]), [np.zeros(2)]*len(A[1])]

indices = np.array([np.unique(a, True)[1] for a in A])

A = np.array([np.array(arr)[index] for arr, index in zip(A, indices)])
B = np.array([np.array(arr)[index] for arr, index in zip(B, indices)])
```